# How can Perl's `system` proceed without wait for the completion.

Tags: perl, system

In Perl, the `command`, will wait till the "command" is completed. Is there a way to let `command` wait only for 20 sec ?  One scenario is like the following:

The `command` is an infinite loop and won't finish. The `command` will freeze and the program can't proceed.  What I want to let the program not blocked by `command`.

I know Ruby has a way to do this. Does Perl have a solution?

Thanks,

=Y

Answer (score 6):

Use [`alarm`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html):

```
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required
    alarm 20;
    system("<Your command>")
    alarm 0;
};
if ($@) {
    die unless $@ eq "alarm\n";   # propagate unexpected errors
    # timed out
}
else {
    # didn't
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use 5.010;

my $foo = 123;
my $pidChild = fork(); # All objects before this fork statement will be copied.
given ($pidChild)
{
    when (!defined($_)) {
        die "Cannot fork: $!";
    }
    when ($_ == 0) {
        # The child process goes here.
        $foo = 456; # This is a duplicate.
        system 'subprocess options'; # Or: exec 'suprocess options';
    }
    default {
        # The original process goes here.
        waitpid($_, 0); # Whether to wait or not is up to you.
        say $foo; # Output: 123
    }
}
```

If Inter-Process Communication (IPC) is needed, before the invocation of `fork`, the built-in function `pipe` can be used to create 2 handlers, one for input and another for output, they'll be shared by the original process and the subprocess.

There's surely more than one way to do IPC. The built-in function `open`, the subroutine `open2` offered by the module IPC::Open2, and the `open3` offered by IPC::Open3 all can run a subprocess asynchronously.